# Logical equivalencies

Tags: logic

Im having a problem showing that these two are the same using logical equivalencies. Any suggestions on how to get started?

$\neg(p\vee(q\wedge\neg r))\wedge q\equiv\neg p\wedge(q\wedge r)$

Comment: I have added some math formatting to your question.  Can you double check that what I wrote down matches your intention?

Answer (score 4):

\begin{eqnarray}
\lnot ( p\lor (q \land \lnot r)) \land q &=&
(\lnot p \land \lnot(q \land \lnot r)) \land q \\
&=& (\lnot p \land (\lnot q \lor r)) \land q \\
&=& (\lnot p \land (\lnot q ) \land q ) \lor (\lnot p \land r \land q ) \\
&=& \lnot p \land r \land q
\end{eqnarray}
The first and second steps follow from De Morgan. The third step is from the distributive property and the last step from the law of non contradiction.

Comment: Oops, I switched true & false by mistake.

Comment: When i looked at the row of the truth table with p,q as false and r as true both sides are false?

Comment: @Matt: You are correct, I misread the question (I missed the $\land q$ at the end of the first expression). I will correct my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the left hand side is true precisely when $p \vee (q \wedge \sim r)$ is false, and $q$ is true.

The latter part of this means (clearly) that $q$ has to be true.

With regard to ensuring $p \vee (q \wedge \sim r)$ is false, you already know $q$ is true; so you will need to ensure that $\sim r$ is false, i.e., that $r$ is true (so that $q \wedge \sim r$ is false), and that $p$ is false.

Now we know when the left side is true: $p$ false; $q$ true; $r$ true.

Observe next that these conditions make the right side true.

Can you perform a similar analysis to show precisely when the right hand side is true, and that this will make the left hand side true as well?